# Reduce memory consumption of numpy function

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a Numpy function that takes the values of an existing array `X` and a size (int) `k` equivalent to the columns of the array. This function does some calculations in a new array, to finally output the new array after the calculations are done.

```
def ff(x, k):
    newarr = np.zeros((x.shape[0], 1), dtype=np.uint32)
    newarr[:, 0] = x[:, 0] * 4
    for i in range(1, k - 1):
        newarr[:, 0] += x[:, i]
        newarr[:, 0] = newarr[:, 0] * 4
    newarr[:, 0] += x[:, -1]
    return newarr
```

`newarr` it's the array where the calculated data is stored, it's initialized with `np.zeros` and a `dtype`, and it has a shape of `(y,1)` where `y` is the length of the `x` array.

The first step is to store in the (only) column of the `newarr` the multiplication of the first column of the `x` by 4.

The iteration occurs over the columns `1 to k-1` of the original array (`x`).
Inside the iteration, the next step is to sum the values of the first column of `x` to the column of `newarr`.
Next, to multiply the column of `newarr` by 4
To finally, after the iteration is complete, sum the last column of the original array `x` to the column of `newarr`.

I'm looking for a way (if there's any) to avoid the creation of the `newarr`, and do the calculations in the original array. This', to reduce the memory usage of this function, mainly because the `x` tends to be very big in execution.

The `x` array looks like this.

```
array([[3, 3, 0, 1],
       [3, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 2],
       [1, 0, 2, 2],
       [0, 2, 2, 3],
       [2, 2, 3, 1],
       [2, 3, 1, 3],
       .
       .
       .
       [2, 2, 0, 1]], dtype=uint8)
```

In this case, the `k` value would be 4.

**Edit**

For the sake of completeness, I've attached the memory profile of my solution and the proposed dot product, for a big `x` array: (248956413, 10).

My solution

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
18    322.0 MiB    322.0 MiB   @profile
19                             def ff(x, k):
20    322.0 MiB      0.0 MiB       newarr = np.zeros((x.shape[0], 1), dtype=np.uint32)
21   1271.7 MiB    949.8 MiB       newarr[:, 0] = x[:, 0] * 4
22   1274.2 MiB      0.0 MiB       for i in range(1, k - 1):
23   1274.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           newarr[:, 0] += x[:, i]
24   1274.2 MiB      2.5 MiB           newarr[:, 0] = newarr[:, 0] * 4
25   1274.2 MiB      0.0 MiB       newarr[:, 0] += x[:, -1]
26   1274.2 MiB      0.0 MiB       return newarr
```

Dot product.

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
18    321.7 MiB    321.7 MiB   @profile
19                             def ff2(x,k):
20   2221.2 MiB   1899.5 MiB       return x.dot(4 ** np.arange(k - 1, -1, -1))
```

I was expecting a reduction in memory usage. Clearly, I was wrong.

Comment: This looks like a simple matrix product, with a power series: `x.dot(4**np.arange(k-1,-1,-1)) `.  `newarr` is only one column, or 1d, a fraction of the size of `x` (with `k` columns).  I wouldn't worry about memory savings.

Comment: @hpaulj Indeed was a dot product, thanks for that!. But for the sake of completeness, I've attached the memory profile of both functions. Weird at least!

Comment: @hpaulj: Would you mind making your comment up into a short answer (maybe explain your thought process as well, or add some memory profiling as OP did) so that this question gets out of the large pool of unanswered questions?